# Unable to Install OBS

Tags: apt

I'm a super new Linux user and need some help installing OBS. I go through the steps on [this](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/ubuntu-14-04-14-10-15-04-ppa-installation-instructions.16495/) page (and have tried others). The error I get is this:

```
W: Failed to fetch ht tp://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch ht tp://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Which version of ubuntu you use ?

Comment: 15.04,  just installed today

Comment: can you provide me the output of `etc/apt/sources.list` ?

Comment: @orvi how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you notice that 15.04 version doesnt need `FFmpeg` package to run obs :

> If you're on Ubuntu 14.04/14.10, you'll first need to install FFmpeg
>   **(15.04+: skip this step):**

Run following command to remove ffmpeg ppa :

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next
sudo apt-get update
```

as a safer alternative, you can use `ppa-purge` :

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && 
sudo ppa-purge ppa:kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next
```

Then install OBS :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ffmpeg obs-studio
```

Comment: Yes I did. I think I mightve installed it by accident anyway, but that shouldnt matter right?

Comment: Yep, the error appear because `ppa:kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next` doesnt exist on vivid repository. Oh and you shouldn't run `sudo apt-get purge ffmpeg`, i already edit my answer

Comment: Ah, how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: Simply remove/disable the ppa as my answer describe it

Comment: Sorry didn't see that, works. Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to upvote my answer :D

Comment: Can't yet :/ not enough points